# MongoDB User Roles not restricting access

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I just started to learn MongoDB, and I've already run into a little issue. For some background, I'm using Jetbrain's Webstorm with the Mongo Plugin.

Now, let me explain my problem.

I don't have any users yet, and I was still in the local database. I then did the following commands

```
 use admin
 db.createUser({
     user: "testRead",
     pwd: "password",
     roles: ["read"]
 })
```

So now I am in the Admin Database, and I created a user called "testRead" with one role: read. This user should only be able to do the commands specified in this link: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/. But it can do so much more on my program.

After creating the User (see above), I stopped the server using Ctrl + C. I then restarted it from CMD using the mongod command.

After I got back into my console from Webstorm, I did the following command:

```
 db.auth("testRead", "password")
```

So now I am "signed in" to the "testRead" user account who's only role is "read". I then tested it out.

I tried the following command:

```
 db.test.insert({
      name: "test"
 })
```

Remember, it shouldn't be able to do this, so I was expecting an error or something, but it worked perfectly and returned this...

```
 WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

What the heck is going on?

Comment: Have you turned on auth for your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an admin user in mongo with authorization off so that you can perform actions such as creating users when authorization is turned on. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication-without-bypass/

then turn on authorization in your mongo instance using either `--auth` on the command line or add it to your config file http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization and restart mongo